# XML source for Spark and groupby operation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using `XML` source from `databricks`. Here is my `XML` sample data.

```
<ds Name="abc">
   <node begin="18" end="22" val="Organic" type="type1">
      <hs id="0" begin="18" end="91" />
   </node>
   <node begin="22" end="23" val="Cereal">
      <hs id="0" begin="18" end="91" />
   </node>
   <node begin="23" end="25" val="Kellogs" type="type2">
      <hs id="0" begin="18" end="91" />
   </node>
   <node begin="22" end="23" val="Harry" type="type1">
      <hs id="1" begin="108" end="520" />
   </node>
   <node begin="23" end="25" val="Potter" type="type1">
      <hs id="1" begin="108" end="520" />
   </node>
</ds>
```

I want to combine all the `node.val` (*in the same order as they appear in the `XML` file] grouped by the `hs id`*).

**For example, o/p for the above data should be:**

> Name   hs id    Val
>
> abc     0     Organic Cereal
>
> abc     1     Harry Potter

Here is where I am loading the XML source from databricks:

```
val df = sqlContext.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
.option("rowTag", "ds")
.option("attributePrefix", "")
.load(args(0))

df.registerTempTable("ds")
```

I am not sure how to group the dataset by `hs id`, and ensure that the order is retained.

```
val  df_ds = sqlContext.sql("SELECT Name, node.type from ds")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val comb = udf((rows: Seq[Row]) => {
  val result = LinkedHashMap[Long, Array[String]]()
  for (row <- rows) {
     val id = row.getAs[Row]("hs").getAs[Long]("id")
     result(id) = result.getOrElse(id, Array[String]()) :+ row.getAs[String]("val")
  }
  result.values.toArray.map(x => x.mkString(" "))
})

df.printSchema
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- node: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- begin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- end: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hs: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- #VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- begin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- end: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: string (nullable = true)

df.withColumn("comb", comb(df("node")))
```

Comment: There was a small bug in the code:   I had to replace the line with this:      result(id) = result.getOrElse(id, Array[String](id.toString)) :+ row.getAs[String]("pos")